# Roblox Studio Is not loading

Tags: roblox, roblox-studio

Whenever I try to edit the place file, it continuously just tries to open the place file, but never does. It doesn’t crash, or stop loading the file; just keeps on trying to open it up and never doing so. I don’t have any problems with files that are not TeamCreate.

How Often: So far, it’s happened each time I’ve tried to open the place file.

Where: When loading the place file via website and studio app.

First Occurrence: I’ve never experienced this bug before, up until creating a place under a group, and then making it TeamCreate. One time, when we switched the game to TeamCreate, the person who switched it (the other was not in the place file at all) could not load the place file, basically same problem, continuously trying to open the place file. Anyways, I got a pretty decent PC that can handle an engine like Roblox Studio.

Here is a example (note: I was just using free models to get an idea of what my model was going to look like)

[image]

Comment: It might have something to do with some of your plugins. Have you tried disabling them before opening the place? When you first open Studio, go to File > Advanced Options > Plugin Management. Turn off your plugins, then try to open the place.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to reinstall ROBLOX Studio or in ROBLOX Studio, on the top left corner, click "FILE", click "Settings", and click "Reset All Settings".